# Php PDO is not working properly when passing params to query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, methods, pdo

I have the following php code, i am trying to execute the associated query with php PDO, the problem is in the

```
WHERE :sno IN(:counselType)
```

Here is my code:

```
//--------------------- PHP code and Query with Array for passing the params ------------

$counselType = $_POST['counselType'];
    $counselType = $counselType == 1 ? "plaintiffAdvocateCC" : "defendantAdvocateCC";
    $ary = array(':sno'=>$_POST['counselSno'],':counselType'=>$counselType);
    //echo $counselType; print_r($bindVar);
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.caseSno,cs.caseNumber,cs.dateOriginalInstitution,CONCAT(cs.plaintiff,' V/S ',cs.respondant) AS caseTitle, cs.caseNature,cs.inTheCourt,
            c.dateOfHearing,c.isDecided,c.stageOfProceedings 
            FROM 
                chronologicallists c,cases cs 
            WHERE 
                :sno IN(:counselType) AND c.caseSno = cs.sno
            GROUP BY c.caseSno
            ORDER BY c.isDecided ASC";
    if($db->dbQuery($sql,$ary)){
        foreach($db->getRecordset($sql,$ary) as $row){
          //------- other code
               }
      }//if search

//------------------------------The Function in the class which handle the queries -------------
function for if search
public function dbQuery($sql,$bindVars=array()){
        try{
            $this->connect();
            $statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute($bindVars);
            if($statement->rowCount() > 0){
                return true;
                }
            else{
                return false;
                }
            }catch(PDOException $exc){
                $this->tempVar = $exc->getMessage();
                $this->sqlToReturn = $sql;
                return false;
                }
            $this->con = null;
        }   
---------------------------------------------------------------------
function for returning the RecordSet array

public function getRecordSet($sql,$bindVars=array()){
            try{
                $this->connect();
                $statement = $this->con->prepare($sql);
                $statement->execute($bindVars);
                return $statement->fetchAll();
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                $this->tempVar = $ex->getMessage();
                return false;
                }               
            }//getRecordSet()

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am not sure why the params are not translated by the **PDO**.
Please guide me that where i am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You can't bind tables and columns. This `WHERE :sno` can't be done, but you can assign a variable first `WHERE $sno`

Comment: is there no way to bind columns or table name like :col or :table_name ?

Comment: No, due to how prepared statements work. The query is sent to the server, which parses it into an execution plan (deciding which indexes to use, which tables to join together, etc), and then you send it the data from the bound parameters when you execute the query. The database can't create the execution plan if it doesn't know the tables and columns to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to dynamicly build an string like this

```
$list = ':foo1, :foo2, :foo3';
```

if your input is this

```
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

then you have to bind :foo1 to 'a' and so on

query would look like this

```
WHERE sno IN (:foo1, :foo2, :foo3);
```

seconds problem, :sno is not possible, you cant bind field-names

Comment: is there no way to bind columns or table name like :col or :table_name? if so, then i have already did / solved the problem in the same way, thanks

Comment: i think you don't really geht the concept behind sql and pdo.... sql is a "language", like php... you push a function to your server, then execute it with bound variables (these are the function-parameters).... the function itself will be evaluated, before executing, but without knowing all tables/columns etc, mysql cant evaluate the "function"